# QT5: How to apply one stylesheet to different widgets?

Tags: c++, styles, qml, qt5

I am fairly new to QT and I am playing around with it a bit. I did a lot of android programming in the past. So I really love the android XML-Styling-System where you can change properties for each induviduell gui-element, you can apply styles to buttons (so they look always the same and there is just one place to change properties for all elements the style is applied to) or you can even create themes, so that you set up one set of styles for your whole application.

Is there anything similiar to this in QT? I've seen the stylesheet property to add a stylesheet to a widget. But let's assume I have 20 buttons and they are all suposed to look the same (e.g. all have a green background). Now I can apply a stylesheet to each button. Now I change my mind and I want them red. Do I have to go into each stylesheet again to change it?

I hope my point came across. Btw, what is QML? Seems very powerful but I didn't get it yet. Is it just a different way of styling?

Thanks.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: It's good style to start from Qt documentation reading first. [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) link could be helpful. Or [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-controls-styles-qmlmodule.html). Just googled it.

Comment: Then cut out the question about QML. Apparently it's a different language to style the widgets. I wanna stick to C++ anyways. Btw, as far as I understood you can use both simultaneously!? E.g. to use QML for an animation in your GUI and for the rest C++?

Comment: As far as my first part of the question goes. I could apply a stylesheet to the top-level-entry of my form so that all Buttons look the same but there is no way to do this for all buttons in my application?

Comment: if you want to apply a style to all the controls you just do `qApp->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow }");` and so all `QLineEdit`s will be with yellow bg. In same way you can apply a stylesheet to a form `form->setStyleSheet()` or to only specified control `lineedit->setStyleSheet()`

Comment: That's what I meant. Thanks:)

Comment: Is there actually any good way to theme an app? Do you usually set up a class or function to do all the setStyle-calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector part of the stylesheet language allows you to have rules that apply to all instances of a class, or all instance of classes of the same base classs, etc.

You can set stylesheets on individual widgets or globally, see `QWidget::setStyleSheet()` and `QApplication::setStyleSheet()` respectively.

Comment: I have discovered this option already but it's not exactly what I am looking for. As the instance in my origin post. What if you want to look each button the same and you have 20 forms? In this case you cannot use stylesheets on base-classes like QWidget.

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand. If you want all buttons to have the same styling, you can set a global style sheet that selects on buttons

Comment: And how? As folibis mentioned? qApp->setStyleSheet("QLineEdit { background-color: yellow }");

Comment: Well, yes, obviously with `QPushButton` as the class selector if you have buttons.